# Full page Slide with jQuery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Looking to implement a solution on a personal project but don't know if it is possible. Would love to have two buttons on left and right of page where if clicked would take you to new page or previous page.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

But here's the kicker, There will be fullscreen stretched bg's. and the two arrows will be positioned 100% full width of browser.

Doe's anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you mean something like http://www.bhuman.co.uk ?

Comment: or like : mindthree.com

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides) to create fullscreen slider (i think you want to slider that i see in example website). It has good documentation. And also you can create slider from your html. I mean it doesn't only need images.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend this plugin **Fullpage.js** -  http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section">my section 1</div>
<div class="section">my section 2</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```